# Limit of difference of Gaussians

Tags: limits, functions

For $r>0$ let us define

$$f_r(x) = \exp(-(x-r)^2) - \exp(-(x+r)^2)$$

and define

$$g_r(x) = \frac{f_r(x)}{\max_{a\in\mathbb R} f_r(a)}$$

I noticed that it looks like $g_r(x)$ converges to some "nice" function $g$ for $r\to 0$:

[image]

Is this a known function, or is there a closed form? (I thought it was already hopeless to find the maximum of $f_r$, as $f_r'$ looks quite nasty: $f_r'(x) = 0 \iff \tanh(2rx)x = r$)

---

EDIT: First we can determine the maximum of $f_r$ by solving $f_r'(x) = 0$ for $r \to 0$. It is easy to see that $f_r'(x) = 0 \iff \tanh(2rx)x=r$, and for $r\to 0$ the solution of this equation converges to $x=\sqrt{1/2} = \sqrt{2}/2$. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541120/find-x-as-y-to-0-in-tanh2yxx-y)).

So $\lim_{r\to0} g_r(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{f_r(x)}{f_r( \sqrt{2}/2)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we can determine the maximum of $f_r$ by solving $f_r'(x) = 0$ for $r \to 0$. It is easy to see that $f_r'(x) = 0 \iff \tanh(2rx)x=r$, and for $r\to 0$ the solution of this equation converges to $x=\sqrt{1/2} = \sqrt{2}/2$. (See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541120/find-x-as-y-to-0-in-tanh2yxx-y)).

So $\lim_{r\to0} g_r(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{f_r(x)}{f_r( \sqrt{2}/2)}.$

This can easily be evaluated using your favourite CAS (in this case Maxima):

```
delta(x) := exp(-x^2);
f(x,r) := delta(x-r) - delta(x+r);
g(x) := limit(f(x,r)/f(sqrt(1/2),r),r,0);
print(g(x));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCoAgEIXhfadwOZJiuUy6SiCUIWjY5GJub1a2/B/fi5Z8tKWsW8gWiLNpZhslkLRobjoHJPAdG5C15B89VrK3V/DRZ/gOysF1YoZRaV5ToBiqTOiPDI/nppQb)

And we see that $$g(x) = \sqrt{2} x \exp(1/2 - x^2)$$

---

EDIT: In hindsight this was unsurprising, as by taking the limit $\lim_{r\to 0} f_r(x)$ we were basically (up to scaling of the y-axis) calculating the derivative of $x \mapsto \exp(-x^2)$ which is

$$ 2x \exp(-x^2)  = c \cdot g(x) $$