# Find $x$ as $y\to 0$ in $\tanh(2yx)x = y$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

The equation

$$\tanh(2yx)x=y$$

generates three lines in a x-y-plot, that intersect in two points. As the equation is symmetric in $x$ the two points are just $(a,0), (-a,0)$. But can we find $a$, or at least a sequence that converges to $a$ (for finding approximations of $a$?

[plot from WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tanh(2*y*x)*x+%3D+y+plot+x+%3D+-5+to+5+and+y+%3D+-5+to+5):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tanh(2yx)x=y$ is equivalent with $$x^2=\frac{xy}{\tanh(2xy)}$$ for $xy\neq0$. Letting $xy\to0$, you get $x^2\to\frac12$.

Comment: This is incredibly clever, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After Professor Vector's answer, consider the Taylor expansion of
$$\frac{a}{\tanh(2a)}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2 a^2}{3}-\frac{8 a^4}{45}+O\left(a^6\right)$$ and replace $a$ by $x y$.

Limited to the first term, you have the result already given by Professor Vector.

Adding the next term, you then have $$x^2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2 }{3}x^2 y^2\tag1$$
Adding the next term, you then have $$x^2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2 }{3}x^2 y^2-\frac{8}{45} x^4 y^4\tag2$$ Just for the fun of it, make these contour plots for the ranges $-1 \leq x\leq 1$,  $-1 \leq y\leq 1$. You could be amazed to see how close they are to your.